# How to sort columns multiple columns in spring jpa which has parameters being passed?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a Jpa repository and I need to sort by two columns i order.

```
public interface PetRepository extends JpaRepository<PetClass, PetKey> {
    List<PetClass> findAllByStatusAndWeightAndBirthDateBetween(String status, String weight, Date fromDate, Date toDate);
}
```

First I need to sort it by PetClass's `petHeight` property in ascending order and then by `petLength` property in descending order.
If I needed to sort only one column then I could have done `findAllByStatusAndWeightAndBirthDateBetweenOrderByPetLength` but I can't use two 'orderBy' in one method it seems because it throws an error saying such.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily construct multi sort in repository

```
return this.PetRepository.findAll(Sort.by("status").descending().and(Sort.by("weight")).a cending());
```